# Converting NSSet to Swift Set causes memory error

Tags: swift, xcode, set, nsset

I have a one-to-many CoreData relationship between entities: `Book` and `NoteSection` called `sections_`.

I am converting an `NSSet` created by core data to a swift `Set` using:

```
var sections: [NoteSection] {
    get {
        if let sections = sections_ as? Set<NoteSection> {
            return sections.sorted(by: { $0.order < $1.order })
        }
        return []
    }
    set {
        sections_ = NSSet(array: newValue)
    }
    
}
```

However, this seems to cause a memory error when the book has no `NoteSections`:

[image: Error message]

Is there a safer way to turn a NSSet into a Set and can anyone explain why this memory error happens? Thanks

Edit:

When printing `sections_` at the beginning of the get. The console shows this:

> Optional(Relationship 'sections_' fault on managed object (0x600000231db0) <Book: ...

Comment: The easiest way is to declare the relationship property in the `NSManagedObject` subclass directly as (non-optional) `Set<NoteSection> `

Comment: Is `sections_` a strong property ? It looks like your managed object context may have released it behing your back. You might want to look at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/MO_Lifecycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH31-SW1

Answer (score 0):

This works for me as a getter. If possible you could try to to remove the set and save your NoteSection to the relationship.

```
public var objectsArray: [Object] {
    let set = objects as? Set<Object> ?? []
    return set.sorted {
       $0.id < $1.id
    }
}
```